# GeoRSS in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, xml, georss

is it possible to integrate GeoRSS in Leaflet and how?
Couldn't find any hint.

For example this georss:

http://www.geonames.org/recent-changes.xml

Which looks like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>GeoNames.org recent changes</title>
<link>http://www.geonames.org/recent-changes.html</link>
<description>50 most recent modifications</description>
<item>
<title>Museo Archeologico Statale</title>
<link>http://www.geonames.org/10628777/museo-archeologico-statale.html</link>
<guid>http://www.geonames.org/10628777/museo-archeologico-statale.html#revision=-1</guid>
<description>created</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 19 Aug 2015 16:52:43 +0200</pubDate>
<georss:point>39.08025 17.13105</georss:point>
</item>
<item>
<title>Palazzo Morelli</title>
<link>http://www.geonames.org/10628776/palazzo-morelli.html</link>
<guid>http://www.geonames.org/10628776/palazzo-morelli.html#revision=-1</guid>
<description>created</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 19 Aug 2015 16:52:19 +0200</pubDate>
<georss:point>39.08081 17.13135</georss:point>
</item>

<!-- More Entries Through Here -->

</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: GeoRSS is just XML assembled according to [a spec](http://www.georss.org/) ..so illustrating the data in Leaflet is as simple as [iterating over the XML nodes in your JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4362720/786131)--which is [a little more complex when the XML has namespaces like GeoRSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13119358/786131)--and then placing the points or features in your Leaflet map using any number of approaches for [adding markers](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html), features, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this links. Couldn't get it working myself. But with the help of toms code everything's working out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building from the comment by @elrobis here is an example using jQuery for getting the georss and adding simple markers to a map:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script>
        var lat = 39;
        var lng = 17;
        var zoom = 2;
        var map = L.map('map').setView([lat,lng],zoom);

        // set up the ajax call
        function getXML(url) {
            return $.get(url)
        }

        // fire and handle the result
        getXML('http://www.geonames.org/recent-changes.xml').done(function(xml){
            var output = {}; // restructure the xml as an object
            $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                var nodes = $(this).children();
                $.each(nodes, function(i,node){
                    var name = node.tagName;
                    var value = node.textContent;
                    output[name] = value;
                });
                // build markers from the output and add to the map
                var marker = L.marker([output['georss:point'].split(' ')[0], output['georss:point'].split(' ')[1]]);
                var popupContent = output.description; 
                marker.bindPopup(popupContent)
                marker.addTo(map);
            });
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW...would it be possible to update the marker layer every x second? Only the marker layer not a whole reload of the page, cause that would change the view. Thanks

Comment: I also added some more content to the popups. Got a problem with the link inside the popup. It apears blueish but does not get the right link. Any idea how I need to change the code? Here the [JSFiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/a76m16ev/)

Comment: the links just needed a bit of formatting, I prefer single quotes then you can use double quotes in the html: http://jsfiddle.net/a76m16ev/1/

Comment: for updating markers, you could [use setInterval or setTimout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188145/call-a-javascript-function-every-5-seconds-continously). You would have to remove the markers before adding them again - maybe with a layerGroup. It would be better to know if there were changes during the interval - maybe they publish that?

Comment: hey tom, thanks but would you mind to help me implementing it?

Comment: I noticed that the service itself is sometimes down. You can use one of the previous fiddles to confirm that you have data from the feed. Here it is with timeout: http://jsfiddle.net/a76m16ev/4/

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add a `fitBounds` to the markers. Changed `layerGroup` into `featureGroup` but then the markers don't show up. Any idea? (http://jsfiddle.net/a76m16ev/5/)

Comment: not sure exactly - one problem is that you can't fitBounds() on markers when it's empty, so you'll need to test for that. There may be other problems.. the console is useful even in jsfiddle..